# emacs follow-mode across frames

Tags: emacs, frame

Is there a way to get behavior like you find in follow-mode but have it across multiple windows in separate frames?

I've gotta work with some nasty legacy code that has seven page bricks of eight-level-deep nested for loops with lots'a goto's and it helps to see as much of the code as possible (in order to adequately understand and rewrite it without breaking everything else).

The more code I can see at once, the better.

Comment: This limitation exists for two reasons: 1) there is no natural "first frame", so it would be hard for follow-mode to figure out in which order to arrange the content of the windows. 2) It allows a user to open several frames, each displaying different parts of the buffer. Why don't you use one big frame -- mine is six columns wide spreading across two physical monitors, which gives me a total of 888 lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This restriction is set explicitly by `follow-all-followers` in its call to `get-buffer-window-list`, so it could be lifted with this change:

```
   (let ((windows (get-buffer-window-list
-                  (window-buffer win) 'no-minibuf (window-frame win))))
+                  (window-buffer win) 'no-minibuf t)))
```

You could redefine that like so:

```el
(defun my-follow-all-followers (&optional win)
  "Like `follow-all-followers' but for all frames.
Passes t as the ALL-FRAMES arg to `get-buffer-window-list'."
  (unless (window-live-p win)
    (setq win (selected-window)))
  (let ((windows (get-buffer-window-list
                  (window-buffer win) 'no-minibuf t)))
    (sort windows #'follow--window-sorter)))

(advice-add 'follow-all-followers :override #'my-follow-all-followers)
```

There are some deficiencies you'll notice pretty quickly (e.g. you may need to arrange the frames manually), but it facilitates the basic requirement of utilising all frames, and you should be able to get it working.

I would also suggest that [FrameMove](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FrameMove) with WindMove might prove very useful for this arrangement.

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to get this to work. I think I'm missing how I'm supposed to invoke it, or how to arrange the frames manually.

Comment: The implementation of `follow-all-followers` changed between 2012 and 2023 (in Emacs 25 by the looks of it), and so the old code in the answer wasn't achieving anything any more.  That's always a potential risk with advice.  I've replaced it with an approach which should work in current versions.

Comment: Works great, many thanks!